# JavaScript: is there a way to detect that a given date in such a format is within last X days?

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of timestamp formatted like this

```js
const dates = ['2021.6.01', '2021.6.11', '2021.9.02']
```

I wanted to write a util that can tell me if a date with such a format is within the last X days of another date.

For example, `2021.6.10` is within the last 7 days of `2021.6.12` while `2021.6.01` is not within the last 7 days of `2021.6.12`.

I was think the API interface would be but please feel free to suggest a better naming

```js
function isWithinTheLastDays(originalDate, date, days)
```

I found it really tricky to implement by hand and there are a lot of edge cases.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the dates with the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date), subtract the two dates and convert the millisecond difference to days (by dividing by 86400000), then check whether it is smaller or equal to `days`:

```js
function isWithinTheLastDays(originalDate, date, days){
  return (new Date(date) - new Date(originalDate)) / 86400000 <= days;
}

console.log(isWithinTheLastDays('2021.6.10', '2021.6.12', 7)) //2 day diff
console.log(isWithinTheLastDays('2021.6.10', '2021.6.17', 7)) //7 day diff
console.log(isWithinTheLastDays('2021.6.10', '2021.6.18', 7)) //8 day diff
```

Comment: I do not know why this answer has been DVed while it meets the requirement precisely.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

Note: this will return true if the dates is X days *after and before* the date you've set

```js
const dates = ['2021.08.26', '2021.6.11', '2021.9.02']

function isWithinDays({ originalDate, date, range }) {
  return parseInt(((new Date(date) - new Date(originalDate)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)), 10) <= range && parseInt(((new Date(date) - new Date(originalDate)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)), 10) >= 0 ? true : false
}

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  console.log(isWithinDays({
    originalDate: dates[i],
    date: new Date('2021-08-27'),
    range: 10
  }))
}
```

Comment: `getDate()` returns the day of the month. Subtracting the day of the month for the two dates will only return the difference in days if they are in the same month.

Answer (score -1):

turning it to Unix timestamp and subtracting it

```
function isWithinTheLastDays(originalDate, date, days){
    if(Math.abs(
    new Date(date).getTime()/1000
    - new Date(originalDate).getTime()/1000
    )/60/60/24 >= days){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    };
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).